# GCM push to production build app not in Play Store

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

### Background

Note: This is not an Urban Airship specific question, though UA is a big reason for why I need things a specific way and cannot accept some answers.

I am doing this because of the way Urban Airship handles delineating development vs. production apps. In the UA console you specify that an app is either development or production and you give Apple, Google, etc. credentials. The iOS app is built as a production Enterprise App, meaning that Apple allows me to distribute it within my company without placing it in the App Store. Therefore, it is a Production app (doesn't use Apple's sandbox server) in UA. I need to configure the GCM side of the same "UA app" and therefore it will be considered production as well.

### Questions

1. Can I create an Android app with a Package Name that is NOT registered with Google Play (because it will only ever be distributed internally) and send push notifications to it?
2. Can I do this compiling it as a production/release version of the app and use Google production GCM API?

### Clarification

That last question is important because I can push to both APNS and GCM in a single step if they are both production or both development. If APNS is production (which it must be because of Enterprise distribution) and GCM is development, then you have to send 2 pushes (one for each).

Comment: To 1: you just need a 'configuration file' - follow this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: To 2: it is up to you whether you consider the Google Developer Project as production or development. GCM does not consider how you treat the particular developer project.

Comment: @kroikie If that is true, how does Google keep from sending pushes intended for development builds to your users with production builds?

Comment: When your client app gets an InstanceID token it specifies which sender (Google Developer Project) is allowed to send it messages.

Answer (score 0):

It will work just fine. The production flag in the UA config is used to select between log level, app key, and app secret.

Comment: So you are saying that for GCM there isn't a different push server used for development vs. production as there is for APNS? (For APNS development pushes you add `sandbox` to the hostname.)

Comment: Yep, you can reuse the sender ID for both production and development